# Statistics on drupal projects

Tags: community-official-site

I am trying to contribute Drupal modules and placed my first project on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org).

Is it possible to see if a proprietary project on drupal.org has been downloaded and how many times?

Comment: Every project has a download/install tracker at the bottom of the page, updated at the start of every week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the "Usage statistics" page of any module on drupal.org, which includes all sorts o relevant information.

As an example, checkout the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, for which you can find those statistics at https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/rules . Apart from a nice chart, it also gives you the statistics by Drupal Release (D6, D7, D8), and this for each Drupal Release for which the module does have some release. If you scroll to the bottom of those statistics, you even get more details (for the last 5 weeks) of every (minor) release of the module.

Attention: don't confuse "using a module" with "number of dowloads of a module"! E.g, for the Rules module, there are currently **296,819** sites reporting that they are using this module, while there have been **2,642,716 downloads** so far. Open question: does that mean that only (about) 10% of sites for which this module was downloaded actually still use this module? Answer: I don't think so ...

PS: Replace "rules" in the above URL by any other module's name to find similar statistics.

Comment: I've always thought that the true number for modules was much higher than tracked. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Kevin you could well be right. Part of that depends on the fact if a site (which has module X enabled) also "reports back" to drupal.org about it (ie via the "check for updates" of such module). Moreover, I cannot believe that there are only about 25% of all sites that have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (as in my sample) enabled. I bet there are at least 50% of all sites that have this module enabled (so there should be at least 500.000 such sites).

Comment: @Kevin, they also state that at the top of the usage page. It only tracks sites that have the update module enabled and have contacted Drupal.org. Sites without that module, or that for instance do not have cron properly set up (and as such do not periodically check) are left out.

Comment: The Views number for Drupal 7 seems low to me as well, since that module is basically installed in every Drupal site since version 5.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, you just beat me. It is hard to say, but everything Rules can do can be done with a custom module as well (rules just binds to every available hook). There are probably many people that prefer a custom module that invokes just one hook over rules that makes every request marginally slower because it listens to all hooks, checks with the database if a rule is listening, etc. Rules is great, but for high performant websites there are reasons to leave it out. On the other hand, there are reasons to keep it if you listen to lots of different hooks.

Comment: @Kevin, do not forget that views is by many considered an advanced modules. If you use Drupal as wordpress, like a simple blogging platform you do not need views.

Comment: Except I don't use the blog module, never have. I'd just build the article list with views because its more customizable.

Comment: @Kevin, yea, me too... But I can imagine there are many sites out there without realizing they need views ;) I was just trying to explain why the number is not the same as the # of D7 installs.